# Using bash with screen in an alias

Tags: linux, alias, gnu-screen

I have a `screen` session that is always running in a separate user (for a minecraft server). Each time I want to attach to this screen, I use `su -c 'screen -r mc-1.18.2' minecraft` to attach back to this screen.

I wanted to make an alias for this command just so I didn't have to type it out or go up in the command history each time. I added `alias mcconsole="su -c 'screen -r mc-1.18.2' minecraft"` to my ~/.bash_aliases folder. My other aliases work just fine but when I run `mcconsole` I am left with a brand new `screen` session. I am not sure where the hiccup is when attaching to the screen session (which is running as I can attach to it normally).

Comment: The alias should work just like typing the command by itself. I can't think of a reason why it would start a new session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe try to invert simple and double quotes, something like:

`alias mcconsole='su -c "screen -r mc-1.18.2" minecraft'`

or escape double quotes inside:

`alias mcconsole="su -c \"screen -r mc-1.18.2\" minecraft"`

Comment: Correction, I forgot to update my aliases. This solution works great!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something screwy is happening with quoting when using the alias. Try using a shell function instead.

```
mcconsole() {
    su -c 'screen -r mc-1.18.2' minecraft
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! When making a function, if I want it to be accessible in any scope like an alias, do I place it in `~/.bashrc` or a different file?

Comment: You can put it in `.bash_aliases` and it will be defined just like your aliases.

Comment: This solution also works but I had some trouble getting it to work with `sudo`. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I don't see why that would be any different.

Comment: This might just be from being a bit uninformed, but I get a "command not found" when I use sudo to this function. I fixed this for the alias solution by adding `alias sudo='sudo '` to my `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: You can't run aliases or functions with `sudo`, only external commands.

Comment: Put sudo in the function body, rather than trying to run the function with sudo.

Comment: `sudo -u minecraft screen -r mc-1.18.2`